# Specific Date Filter in Macro

Tags: vba, excel, datefilter

Below is my code for specific date filter from 01-02-2018 to 10-02-2018.
I don't get runtime error but it filter from 01-01-2018 until 14-02-2018.

I have A to P column and n no.of rows also dates were in J column

```
Sub Date_Filter()
   Dim WeekS As Date
   Dim WeekE As Date
   WeekS = "01-02-2018"
   WeekE = "10-02-2018"
Range("A1:P1").AutoFilter
        Selection.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & WeekS, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & WeekE
End Sub
```

Comment: Should the **second** date be *February 10th* or *October 2nd*??

Comment: 01-Feb-2018 to 10-Feb-2018

Comment: Very new to macro.. in actual i need to auto filter from  thur to wed every week

Comment: thurs  to wed each week? that is the entire week

Comment: Also without editing macro for each week(start n end date)... Is there any other way i could filter?

Answer (score 0):

Please examine this changes we made here:

```
Sub Date_Filter()
   Dim WeekS As Date
   Dim WeekE As Date


   WeekS = DateSerial(2018, 2, 1)
   WeekE = DateSerial(2018, 2, 10)
   With Range("A1:P1")
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & WeekS, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & WeekE
    End With
End Sub
```

We use *DateSerial()* to avoid any confusion between US and European date standards.

[image]

Comment: No mate :( above macro did not worked.. It shows as such it filters but actually didn't

Comment: @SahanaG  make sure the values are **true** dates and not just text.

Comment: I Have once again format the J column with Date still it doesn't work.. Sorry for troubling help me out to fix this up

Comment: Below code helped me.. Thanks                                                          Sub Date_Filter()

   Dim WeekS As String
   Dim WeekE As String
WeekS = ">=" & Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Start Date", Default:=Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy"), Type:=2)
WeekE = "<=" & Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter End Date", Default:=Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy"), Type:=2)
Range("A:N").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=WeekS, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=WeekE

End Sub

Comment: @SahanaG  Good Job! ................... this is a very good way to force standard date input.................